# How can i know whether CXF use JIBX Databinding or not?

Tags: cxf, jibx

I am working with Apache CXF for Web Service's Client app. I am intending to use JIBX Databinding for that.

When I tested my application, I got the below log. I am confused whether my application use JIBX Databinding from the log due to the fact that the list of "Interceptors contributed by binding" doesn't include an inteceptor related with JIBX.

I have little knowledge of CXF and JIBX. Please let me know about that.

Thanks in advance.

```
----------------------------------
Part of Logging 
........
2012. 11. 23 오후 4:49:28 org.apache.cxf.jibx.JibxDataBinding initialize
더 자세히: Initialize JiBX Databinding for [{http://server.sample.prototype.topas/}TopasPrototypeWebServiceServerService] service
........

자세히: Interceptors contributed by binding: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@14dd758, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@174d93a, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@61a907, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.WrappedOutInterceptor@1a0225b, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor@2f8b5a, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@165c7f6, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@12aea3e]
.........
------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure that CXF uses interceptors for data bindings at all; they're plugged into a different stage of the processing. How are you telling CXF about the JIBX stuff in the first place?

Comment: I provided a simple Apache CXF with JiBX sample application [here](https://github.com/FrVaBe/cxf-soap-with-jibx#readme) and blogged about it [here](http://frvabe.blogspot.de/2013/04/using-apache-cxf-soap-service-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Paulius,

There are several examples at the JiBX web site.

Implementing a CXF SOAP server using JiBX:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/webservice.html

Implementing a RESTful service using JiBX:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/rest.html

Good Luck!

Don Corley
JiBX contributor